# Can I use my internet connection for the setup of a Ubuntu VM without Internet connection

Tags: linux, networking, ssh

I got a Linux VM set up in a corporate environment to host an application. Sadly it does not have active internet connection. Is there a way to use the internet-connection from my client while I am connected via `SSH`-session for things like `curl` or would I need to download things manually and send them via `FTP` to set things up (e.g. tomcat)?

I am using `Bitvise SSH Client` at the moment if that is helpful at all.

Comment: Setting up a vpn-over-ssh would be a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Reverse Tunneling](https://fogbugz.bitvise.com/default.asp?Tunnelier.2.6229.4) and then configure curl to use the reverse tunnel as [a proxy](https://sanctum.geek.nz/arabesque/ssh-socks-and-curl/)